Definition of Entropy of probability density function
Definition of entropy of probability density function $f\ge 0$ is
$$Ent(f)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\log f(x)dx$$
My question is how this definition defines an integral on a set such that f is zero.
$0\log0$ is $0$?or $-\infty$?
Also, is there a probability density $f$ such that $Ent(f)=+\infty$?

I don't know much about this topic but I'll summarize this Wikipedia article. I also think you forgot a minus sign in your definition as the wikipedia article has a minus sign in their definition.
As you would expect from taking the limit as $f(x) \to 0$ of $x\log(x)$, when $f$ is zero we define the integrand to be 0. This also allows us to get a finite entropy when we have $f(x) = 0$. If the integrand were to be $-\infty$ then any function that had $f(x) = 0$ on any set with measure greater than 0 would give us $-\infty$ and this would not be incredible useful.
As for a function $f$ such that $Ent(f) = \infty$: I believe you can make the entropy arbitrarily large, but not necessarily infinite (consider $x^{-\alpha}$ as $\alpha$ goes approaches 1 from the lower side).
For bounded p.d.f.s this is because $f$ is bounded. We have $\int f(x) dx = 1$, so we have that $f \in L^1$. A bounded function in $L^1$ is also in $L^2$ which gives us:
$$ \infty > \int |f(x)f(x)| dx > \int f(x)\log(f(x))dx $$
I don't know how to prove this for unbounded p.d.f.s but I believe the claim still holds.

Thank you very much!
